# Google Places API - Places detail request undefined

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I'm trying to retrieve place details using the Google Places Library. When you click the place marker I want to be able to see the address, name, website etc.

I'm using the following tutorial:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

All seems to be going pretty well. In my marker I can display the name and the rating but the address, website and phone number all appear as 'undefined'. Is this because Google doesn't have the information I'm requesting on these places? Or have I done something wrong?

Here's the code I'm using:
        var map;
      var infowindow;

```
  function initialize() {
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: 5000,
      types: ['bar']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name + "<br />" + place.formatted_address +"<br />" + place.website + "<br />" + place.rating + "<br />" + place.formatted_phone_number);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
```

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

JA

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're doing a Place Search, which doesn't return all of the fields that you're using:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_search_responses

In order to get the address, website, etc, you'll also need to call `place.getDetails()`, passing the Place's `reference`. See:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_details_requests

Roughly, your code would change to:

```
  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var request = { reference: place.reference };
    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: No problems! Glad I could help :)

Comment: hi.. i am facing the same issue and tried this solution. but unable to get result ." service.getDetails(request, function(details, status)" where to declare this service variable ? do i need to declare this again in create marker function ?

Comment: Hi Thakur. The `service` variable is defined as a global variable in the `initialize()` function. See the original question for the code: `service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);`

Comment: Here is link of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547932/google-places-api-location-marker-pop-up-showing-at-wrong-place , i have tried same code but not getting place, latitude,etc and  also marker popups are not shown on their own location. Its showing all markers on last added marker.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mikes response above I would suggest moving the call into the listener like below. This way the call to the API is only made when a user clicks the marker instead of hundreds of times in cases where one renders a lot of markers.

```
function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var request = { reference: place.reference };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
      infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
});
```

}