# Google Places API Periods[] Not Showing

Tags: json, rest, google-places-api

New to Google Places API. But I can't seem to get "Opening Hour" Periods[] to display. From the Google Doc:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Places API - Places detail request undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520808/google-places-api-places-detail-request-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the opening_hours aren't returned for this type of call. To get place details you'll need to have the place's `placeId` and make a call to `place.getDetails()`.

There's another SO answer that should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9523345/2141296