# How to obtained Google Place ID?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-maps-api-3, powerbi, powerquery

I've tried using Google Maps API connecting to Microsoft PowerBI with the following Web connector method: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=54.77614759999999,-1.5605721&radius=2000&type=restaurant&key=INSERT_API_KEY

But this is a "Place Search" and doesn't bring any details such as website or phone numbers etc. To include a "Detail Search" I have to use JavaScript function mentioned in this topic: [Google Places API - Places detail request undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520808/google-places-api-places-detail-request-undefined/9523345#9523345)

I have both PowerBI and Visual Studio but just not used to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Places API endpoint for [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) is at

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters
```

For example,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

where `placeid` can be obtained from the `Place Search` API you used before.

How to automate the process programmatically, whether by JavaScript, VBA or Power BI is up to you, and also depends on how you want to make use of the data afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm not planning to use this anymore since Google doesn't permit. I will find free maps as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some KML-CSV **parser** to have opportunity to open it with Excel

[Here](http://www.convertcsv.com/kml-to-csv.htm) I found one, and it seems works

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot. I'm trying to automate it from Google API instead of using Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

To get a place ID from Google API, your request URL is like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=PLACE_ADDRESS&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Replace these two variables: 'PLACE_ADDRESS' and 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your specific details.

The result returned will be a JSON string which contains the "place_id" among other details as seen below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Are you not trying to do anything that would be against the API Terms of Service?

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5

#### 10.5 Intellectual Property Restrictions.

...

d. **No caching or storage.** You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:

1. is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
2. is secure;
3. does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
4. does not modify attribution in any way.

e. **No mass downloading.** You will not use the Service in a manner that gives you or a third party access to mass downloads or bulk feeds of any Content. For example, you are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content contained in the Maps API(s).

Comment: No. Because it's not mass downloading. 
"Free up to 25,000 map loads per day.3
$0.50 USD / 1,000 additional map loads, up to 100,000 daily, if billing is enabled."
https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

Comment: You want to *get a list of local restaurants from Google Maps into Excel* but you don't say what you want to do with the data afterwards. I was just pointing out that you are not supposed to store data retrieved in any way from Google Maps and/or manipulate that data. So what do you want to do with that data once you have it in Excel?

Comment: My plan is so create a directory of local businesses but it appears that Google does not permit it outside of the Google Map services. Thank you so much for clearing that one up. I understand now that 25K map loads per day only applies if you're improving performance of your Maps API.

Comment: You might find other data sources of course. If that answered your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Would be kind enough to let me know please which other data sources are there for this information? Many thanks!

Comment: No I don't know. But I am sure you can find something. You said "local" businesses so your choice will also depend on the location you are interested in. But SO is not the place to ask for that...